# What are these brush like blue wildflowers on long stems in this mountain picture?

Tags: identification, wildflowers

I saw this image on tumblr and after attempting searches for variations on "blue flowers that grow in the mountains" I have found nothing. The photographer did not list where it was taken either :/, I have asked if they know but have not gotten an answer yet. I will update if i am able to gather any new information https://www.instagram.com/p/BhYp--JDEbu/?taken-by=_starrush
 [image]

Comment: ...............

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it is lupine. The color seems slightly "off-ish" (toward the greenish) in this photo, but colors are tricky. Maybe it's the light, or the cultivar variety, which I wouldn't even make an attempt to identify.

Comment: I would suggest the photo had colour filters over it when taken, or its been altered digitally later to change the colours slightly - the foliage looks almost  dark grey and the flowers seem almost neon blue... Whatever it is, its a member of the Fabaceae